# How to use CSS files on client side?

Tags: html, css

I have client side application. It's some css and js files gets from http connection and they are works fine. But I want to use some icons on my index page. So I created flat icon collection and downloaded it. I gave reference like that:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/css/flaticon/font/flaticon.css"/>
```

and tried to use it like:

```
<i class="flaticon-smart-watch"></i>
```

But I think it's not get any reference so it's show nothing. How can I store and use local css files on client side?

Comment: you can't get CSS file as a resource on your local machine , I mean there is nothing to do by yourself explicitly.  when you add a link to a resource on your page CSS,JS etc, browser send a request for that resource if it cant resolve it from the cache.
you need to see if any error happens when request for flaticon.css has send to your end point.
check the developer tools of your browser for it.

Comment: @HosseinSalmanian That is incorrect. However he cannot get it from / root

Comment: Change to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flaticon/font/flaticon.css"/>` if your css folder is under the folder where you have your page

Answer (score 0):

Open up flaticon.css into your text editor, did you find "flaticon-smart-watch" class inside?

If not, you may want go back to flaticon, pick the smart-watch icon into your collection and redownload the css file.